# How to delete Kubernetes Deployment that are not used so often

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

We have limited amount of resources in our cluster, so we want to implement a service/feature to manage cleaning up Deployments that are not used recently.

We use nginx ingress, and want to know if there is a way to get the request counter for each ingress.

After Googling for hours, I cant see an existing solution for this need.

Is there an opensource solution out there that I'm not aware of?
Please help our guide me if you have experience with this.

Comment: couldn't you check some logs? log of the nginx or your application itself. You could see in the logs if the service was not reached recently.

Comment: No, we don't have any logs and we cant add logs.